# How to type-check the data sent to a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, type-safety

A subclassed Vue component can be initiated like:

```js
let app = new MyApp({    
  el: '#app',    
  data: {    
    message: 'Hello Vue!',    
    seconds: 0    
  },    
  created() {    
    setInterval(() => {    
      this.econds = 'asd';    
    }, 1000);    
  }    
});
```

The problem is, neither Flow nor TypeScript will notice the typo or the wrong type on line `this.econds = 'asd';`. Is there a way to remedy this? Maybe with class-based components library? But then compilation is a needed build step?

Comment: Did you try the official documentation?
https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: @FelipeEndlich Sure! But I'm trying to apply TypeScript without compilation. :)

Comment: OK, maybe my problem is that it's not possible to do generics with classes using only JSDoc.

Comment: Is this inside a .ts file? My IDE would not love to see this...

Comment: @Ferry Kranenburg, no, this is a vanilla .js file.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg See above.

Comment: Use typescript and typescript files, that will alert you for typos like this. In vanilla js this is not a typo, you are just assigning inside 'this' a new property 'econds' with a string. No problem at all in vanilla js.

Comment: What do you mean subclassed component? What is `MyApp`? Is it an instance of `Vue` or a subclass of the `Vue` class?

Comment: @NinoFiliu Can we consider both cases? Want me to expand the question to cover both those cases properly?

Comment: Yes please clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should configure your IDE for this properly.

I am using VSCode and the VSCode Extension **Vetur** https://github.com/vuejs/vetur

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Home',
    data: function() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello Vue!',
            seconds: 0,
        };
    },
    created() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.econds = 'asd';
        }, 1000);
    },
});
</script>
```

In combination with `<script lang="ts">` Vetur tells you for `this.econds` that this does not exist and displays the message:

> Property 'econds' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, { message: string; seconds: number; }, unknown, unknown, Readonly<Record<never, any>>>'. Did you mean 'seconds'?Vetur(2551)

No compile step needed, it is on the fly.

Is this what you need?

Comment: I wish I could downvote my own question, haha. Thank you for your patience. I'll try to open a new, more clear question. Basically I want to use TypeScript with vanilla JS using `// @ts-check` and `// @type` etc, but this was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you're using **Typescript** you can define the type in the variable using class-based components. But that type-check only occurr on the transpilation step. The transpiler will still work will generate the **Javascript** files, which won't type-check the variable.

Another approach would be type-check manually using `typeof(variable) === "number"`. That expression will return true or false, depending on the value of `variable`.

**Approach 1**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
    name: 'Home',
})
export default class extends Vue {
    message: string = "Hello, Vue";
    seconds: number = 0;

    created() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.seconds = 'asd'; // The transpiler will show an error.
        }, 1000);
    },
}
</script>
```

**Approach 2**

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Home',
    data: function() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello Vue!',
            seconds: 0,
        };
    },
    created() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let variable = 'asd'
            if (typeof(variable) === "number")
               this.seconds = variable;
        }, 1000);
    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish I could award you a bounty too for my lousy question.